# Why is dramatiq detecting my PC as 32 bits?

Tags: python, django, dramatiq

I'm trying to run django-dramatiq --watch, but it returns a RuntimeError: Watching for source changes is not supported on win32.

django-dramatiq version:

[image: django-dramatiq version]

dramatiq version:

[image: dramatiq version]

Both my Python installation and my system are 64 bits, so I don't understand the issue

Comment: Yeah, I tried [several searches](https://imgur.com/a/UnTMev2), including possible duplicates offered by SO. If they did help, I wouldn't post this question.

Comment: How about [this one](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=why+is+64+bit+system+called+win32)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`win32` is the generic name for the Windows API on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.  It's saying that operation is not available in Windows.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the polite answer, didn't know that!

Comment: More specifically, I should have said that, in Python, `sys.platform` returns `win32` regardless of the bit size.